# Skip first row in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

We can select `Top 10` or `Select Top 'N'` row from SQL Server.

But is there any way to skip first row from the result of top??

I mean I get result from `select top 5`, then I skip the first row and get only next 4 rows?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `OVER` clause and a ranking function. You can't filter on this directly so you need to us a sub query or a common table expression, the example below uses the latter.

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE 
(
    ID INT,
    Name VARCHAR(15)
);
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES (1, 'Alice');
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES (2, 'Bob');
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES (3, 'Chris');
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES (4, 'David');
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES (5, 'Edgar');

WITH people AS 
(
    SELECT ID, Name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) RN
    FROM @MyTable
)
SELECT ID, Name
FROM people
WHERE RN > 1;
```

There will be better support for pagination in the next version of SQL Server (codename Denali) with the `OFFSET` and `FETCH` keywords.

Comment: Great...i didn't think in this direction. i was trying to select with top 5 then from that i was trying to skip the first with 'skip' word... Thanks a lot... :-)

Comment: +1 for mentioning it's a ranking function - that makes this an even more useful answer

Answer (score 5):

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM (
        SELECT      
            row_number() OVER (ORDER BY ID DESC) AS [rownum],
            *
        FROM
            tbl
) T
WHERE 
    rownum BETWEEN (2) AND (5)
```

**Update:**

Updated to have your values.

**Update 2:**

Corrected error with missing sub query. Thanks to Chris Diver pointing this out.

Comment: ya. i did correct while executing in my sql but forgot to mention it here. :-)

Comment: I used this inside another subquery and it worked great! The other `;WITH`... solution doesn't work in that case.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is the term paging.
Like this: http://www.15seconds.com/issue/070628.htm

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
-- Test table
declare @T table(ID int);

-- Add test data
insert into @T 
select 1 union all
select 2 union all
select 3 union all
select 4 union all
select 5 union all
select 6;

-- Query using row_number() over(...)
-- to get rows 2 - 5
select T.ID
from (
        select *,
               row_number() over(order by ID) as rn
        from @T       
     ) as T
where T.rn between 2 and 5;
```