# SELECT first 3 rows after 8th row

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table: `id, Group, Status, Subject`.

I need rows where group=2 AND status=2, but I want to skip the first 8 results (ordered by `id`). This is what I tried, but it does not skip the first 8 rows:

```
SELECT TOP 3 [id], LEFT ([subject],30) AS Title 
FROM [Katavot] 
    WHERE (([Status] = @Status) AND ([Group] = @Group)) 
ORDER BY [id] DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;WITH Katavod_Modified AS 
(
    SELECT id, LEFT ([subject],30) As Subject, [Group], [Status],  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) RN
    FROM [Katavot]
)
SELECT TOP 3 [id], LEFT ([subject],30) AS Title FROM [Katavod_Modified] WHERE 
(([Status] = @Status) AND ([Group] = @Group) AND (RN > 8)) ORDER BY [id] DESC
```

Looks very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137889/skip-first-row-in-sql-server-2005).

Answer (score 1):

Based on [row_number](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

```
WITH MyResult AS
{
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Id DESC) AS RowNumber, [id], LEFT ([subject],30) AS Title 
FROM [Katavot] 
    WHERE (([Status] = @Status) AND ([Group] = @Group)) 
ORDER BY [id] DESC
}
SELECT [id], Title 
FROM MyResult
WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN 9 AND 12
```

Answer (score -1):

MySQL:

```
LIMIT x, y
```

MSSQL:

```
select top y *
from <table>
where <unique id> not in (select top x <unique id> from <table> order by <unique id>)
from <table> order by <unique id>
```