# How to use limit in Microsoft SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008

We have to use Limit keyword in SQL server 2008/2012.

We need to apply limit for every query where start index will change every time. When I was googling found TOP but it won't work for us. Can anyone please share how to use LIMIT keyword in sql server where every time start index change.

We need query in SQL server like below -

```
SELECT * from STOCK LIMIT 11, 10000 (where 11=start index, 10000=size)
```

Comment: There is no `LIMIT` in SQL Server. So you can't use it. What exactly is "*TOP won't work for us*" supposed to mean?

Comment: If 2012 you can use [offset-fetch](http://stevestedman.com/2012/04/tsql-2012-offset-and-fetch/)

Comment: `LIMIT` is a MySQL/Postgres-specific extension which isn't generally available in all SQL databases (and it's not part of the SQL language standard, either).

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL LIMIT clause equivalent for SQL SERVER](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9013177/mysql-limit-clause-equivalent-for-sql-server)

Comment: With the help of offset and fetch we could resolve the issue of LIMIT in SQL server 2012.  
Example - SELECT ITEM_ID, PRICE FROM MENU
 ORDER BY ITEM_ID ASC
 OFFSET 10 ROWS
 FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not a good long-term solution for you, but if the table has an Identity field you could do something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM STOCK
WHERE Id > 11
ORDER BY Id
```

Comment: We have migrated to SQL server 2012 and replaced LIMIT with OFFSET and FETCH. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use a CTE with a window function, like in the answer to this SO question -> [Skip first row in SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137889/skip-first-row-in-sql-server-2005)

Comment: We have migrated to SQL server 2012 and replaced LIMIT with OFFSET and FETCH. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use something like the [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) function and then specify what you want from there.

```sql
select top 10000 *, row_number() over (order by [YourFieldName]) as row from Stock where row > 11
```

Comment: With the help of offset and fetch we could resolve the issue of LIMIT in SQL server 2012.  
Example - SELECT ITEM_ID, PRICE FROM MENU
 ORDER BY ITEM_ID ASC
 OFFSET 10 ROWS
 FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;

Answer (score -1):

We have upgraded to SQL server 2012 and replaced query with OFFSET and FETCH. Sample is below.

```
SELECT ITEM_ID, PRICE FROM MENU ORDER BY ITEM_ID ASC OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```